# Knockout JS not setting all members observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mapping

What I am trying to do is to get data from the server and then putting it all in an observable and then make all the properties observable. The issue I am facing is that it does not make all my properties observable and I need them all to be observable as sometimes depending on the data it makes some properties observable and sometimes it doesn't.

```
var viewModel = this;
viewModel.Model = ko.observable();

viewModel.SetModel = function (data) {
viewModel.Model(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
}
```

The data that I am receiving from the server is like this for example: normaldata,items(this is an array with unknown number of elements).
so if i try to access data like `viewModel.Model().Items[0]().Layer()` i sometimes have Layer as a function and sometimes it is a normal element with observable elements.I want all my objects inside Items to have Layer as a function.

Server data example:
Name: "test"
Items: [Layer[ID: 132]]
In this example Name,Items and ID are observable but Layer is not.

Fiddle example:
jsfiddle.net/98dv11yz/3 
So the problem is that sometimes the layer is null resulting in ko making the property observable but sometimes that property has id and ko makes only the child elements observable. The problem is that i have if's in the code and i want it to be a function so i can always reffer to it as layer() because now it is sometimes layer or layer()

Comment: The post is quite hard to understand. Please re-read it and try to clarify, and try to include a [mcve].

Comment: edited ... hope this is good enough!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't help all too much I'm afraid. Have you checked the link from my previous comment? Try to create a *runnable* (but minimal) repro for your situation. From what you've posted so far that seems perfectly possible. (In addition, it also helps if you pay attention to formatting and if possible spelling in your post; there's a live preview when editing.)

Comment: I tried to create a _minimal, complete and verifiable example_ for you, but wasn't able to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/98dv11yz/

@RedDevil, can you fork the fiddle and show us what you mean? I've added comments to a few lines of code to show that the mapped viewmodel does contain observable properties as expected.

Comment: @user3297291 Please, when asking for jsfiddle from a new user, make sure to ask them to include the repro *in the question* as well, otherwise the question will still get closed. Alternatively, you could ask for a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/98dv11yz/3/ I have updated the js fiddle! So the problem is that sometimes the layer is null resulting in ko making the property observable but sometimes that property has id and ko makes only the child elements observable. The problem is that i have if's in the code and i want it to be a function so i can always reffer to it as layer() because now it is sometimes layer or layer()

Comment: Please update your question one last time (like Jeroen requested), including this example; it is now very clear. I'll write down my suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An explenation for what's happening:**

When the `ko.mapping` plugin encounters an object in your input, it will make the object's properties observable, not the property itself.

For example:

```
var myVM = ko.mapping.fromJS({
  name: "Foo",
  myObject: {
    bar: "Baz"
  }
});
```

Will boil down to:

```
var myVM = {
  name: ko.observable("Foo"),
  myObject: {
    bar: ko.observable("Baz")
  }
}
```

and **not** to:

```
var myVM = {
  name: ko.observable("Foo"),
  myObject: ko.observable({
    bar: ko.observable("Baz")
  })
}
```

The issue with your data structure is that `myObject` will sometimes be `null`, and sometimes be an object. The first will be treated just as the `name` property in this example, the latter will be treated as the `myObject` prop.

**My suggestion:**

Firstly: I'd suggest to *only* use the `ko.mapping.fromJS` method if you have a well documented and uniform data structure, and not on large data sets that have many levels and complexity. Sometimes, it's easier to create slim viewmodels that have their own mapping logic in their constructor.

If you do not wish to alter your data structure and want to keep using `ko.mapping`, this part will have to be changed client-side:

```
Items: [
  { layer: {id: "0.2"} },
  { layer: null}
]
```

You'll have to decide what you want to achieve. Should the viewmodel strip out the item with a `null` layer? Or do you want to render it and be able to update it? Here's an example of how to "correct" your data before creating a view model:

```
var serverData = {
  Name: "Example Name",
  Id: "0",
  Items: [
    {layer: {id: "0.2"} },
    {layer: null}
  ]
};

var correctedData = (function() {
  var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(serverData));

  // If you want to be able to render the null item:
  copy.Items = copy.Items.map(function(item) {
    return item.layer ? item : { layer: { id: "unknown" } };
  });

  // If you don't want it in there:
  copy.Items = copy.Items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.layer;
  });

  return copy;
}());
```

Whether this solution is acceptable kind of relies on how much more complicated your real-life use will be. If there's more complexity and interactivity to the data, I'd suggest mapping the items to their own viewmodels that deal with missing properties and what not...